# How to make this function work with FILE? C++

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to write two functions where I pass a `FILE*`, and these functions create another `FILE*` where they put the original data in lowercase and in uppercase without spaces, respectively.

I think I got it, but I don't know how to pass a `FILE*` to a function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

void minusculas (FILE *urFile);
void mayusculas (FILE *urFile);

main(){
    char s[256];
    FILE *pf;
    cout << "Tell me the name of the FIlE: ";
    gets(s);
    pf=fopen(s,"r");
}

void minusculas (FILE *urFile){
    char c; FILE *pf;
    urFile=fopen(urFile,"r");
    pf=fopen ("alliva.txt","w+");
    while (c!=EOF){
        c=getc(pf);
        if (c!=EOF)
            c=tolower(c);
        fprintf(pf,"%c" ,c);
    }
}

void mayusculas (FILE *urFile){
    char c; FILE *pf;
    urFile=fopen(urFile,"r");
    pf=fopen ("alliva.txt","w+");
    while (c!=EOF){
        c=getc(pf);
        if (c!=EOF && isspace(c)==0)
            c=toupper(c);
        fprintf(pf,"%c" ,c);
    }
}
```

I get errors in the functions. How can I make the program better?

Comment: Please make an effort and indent your code properly. Your code as it stands here is unreadable. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Seems to be more C than C++.

Comment: writing code is easier if you dont mix two different languages. The current answer applies to c, for c++ you wouldnt be using `FILE` in the first place

Comment: @user463035818 sorry for that, just using what my teacher told me. I'm trying learning more but I still mix languages since he taught me a bit of both.

Comment: `main()` should be `int main()` (it's unfortunate that some C++ compilers don't complain about `main()`.) And *never* use `gets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pf=fopen(s,"r");
```

In this `pf` represents the `FILE *` or the handle to the opened file. You can pass it around directly in functions. Check man page of [fopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

You can perform operations like `fgetc` or `getc` on the file handle directly.

Apart from this your code needs to handle closing of file by calling `fclose` appropriately at various places.

---

To give you an example of how you can do this, see the below function:

```
void minusculas (FILE *urFile){
    char c; FILE *pf;
    //urFile=fopen(urFile,"r"); This is not needed
    pf=fopen ("alliva.txt","w+");
    while (c!=EOF){
        c=getc(urFile); //If you want to read from urFile
        if (c!=EOF)
            c=tolower(c);
        fprintf(pf,"%c" ,c);
    }
    fclose(pf)
}
```

You can call this function from your main like below:

```
pf=fopen(s,"r");
minusculas(pf)
fclose(pf)
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `fclose()` on every `FILE*` you open.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thanks for your comment. I had just mentioned it in a statement. Now, I updated the code snippet also to reflect the same.